# How can I get an array of custom categories in Wordpress?

Tags: arrays, wordpress, categories, custom-taxonomy

I have registered a custom taxonomy as part of my custom post type, but when passing it through to `get_categories()` it returns an empty array. Any ideas as to why?

```
// Register FAQ Categories taxonomy
function bv_faq_register_categories() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'faq-category',
        'faq',
        array(
            'label'        => 'Categories',
            'rewrite'      => array('slug' => 'faq-category'),
            'hierarchical' => true
        )
    );
}
add_action('init', 'bv_faq_register_categories');

// Category view
$categories = get_categories(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'faq-category'
));
```

`$categories` is returning an empty array.

Comment: I hope it will be useful for you https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried get_terms instead?

```
$categories = get_terms( 'faq-category', array(
    'orderby'    => 'count',
    'hide_empty' => 0
) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok. Do you have assigned this category to any post/post type?
If not then you will get an empty result. for testing you can set `'hide_empty' = false` like this:

```
// Category view
$categories = get_categories(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'faq-category',
    'hide_empty' => false // set it true
));
```

Also, you can use `get_terms()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Like @AD Styles said I would use get_terms using the custom taxonomy, to expand a bit here's some example code:

```
<?php

$post_type = 'faq-category';

// Get all the taxonomies for this post type
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( (object) array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) );

foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) : 

    // Gets every "category" (term) in this taxonomy to get the respective posts
    $terms = get_terms( array( 
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'parent'   => 0
    ) );

    foreach( $terms as $term ) :

        echo "<h1>".$term->name."</h1>";

    endforeach;

endforeach;

?>
```